PropertyNotFoundException during execution of a service task in Camunda 7
My issue is that i am getting org.camunda.bpm.engine.ScriptEvaluationException and org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException.
This is in a scenario when a property and its value is absent in the context/session intentionally and that the property is not initialised in the workflow.
So when the property is being sent like #{xyz} to a service task and when it is absent, customized camunda modeler is throwing this exception.
Possible workarounds as per my research is by adding a timer to this service task, but can someone please let me know if there is an actual solution or how to handle this?
Eloborating the problem :
I have a workflow in which I call a service task/service operation, which is essentially an XML file with components and models. My workflow calls this service operation and has two paths: success and error. The error path is configured to handle failure scenarios, including if the service operation takes more than n minutes to complete.
Now, when I run a scenario, this workflow gets stuck inside the service operation because I am manually deleting a row in the database, which is a property inside the working context(variable). The service operation takes a property as input, which the workflow should send from its context, and this is the property I mentioned earlier as #{xyz}. So when this property is not found, Camunda throws the error mentioned above. However, for some reason, the workflow is not handling the failure/error path that we have configured to exit after n minutes.
If we initialize the variable/property before the service operation executes, the flow works like a charm. However, my problem is that I need to find a way to handle this PropertyNotFoundException so that no matter which property is absent in the context, the flow exits gracefully.
To summarize, the workflow is throwing a Camunda PropertyNotFoundException even before calling the service operation, as it is unable to find the property in its context. I need to find a way to handle this exception. Is there a way in Camunda 7 to handle this?
The workaround I tried by adding a timer boundary event to this service operation didn’t work. As I mentioned, the flow is not reaching the failure path and gets stuck even before reaching the service operation, indefinitely.
